# Set samples in tikzpicture from macro value

Tags: macros, pgfplots

I'm trying to use set the amount of samples per tikzpicture globally:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{gauss}{2}{%
  \pgfmathparse{1/(#2*sqrt(2*pi))*exp(-((x-#1)^2)/(2*#2^2))}%
}
%\samplesize = <number>% How do I get this one to work?
\begin{document}  
\section{Gaussian distribution}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
      hide y axis,
      axis lines*=center, 
      axis on top,
      no markers, 
      domain=2.5:25.5, 
      samples=\samplesize,
      xlabel=\empty, 
      ylabel=\empty,
      every axis x label/.style={at=(current axis.right of origin),anchor=west},
      every axis y label/.style={at=(current axis.above origin),anchor=south},
      height=5cm, width=12cm,
      xmin = 4, xmax=24,
      xtick={14}, ytick=\empty,
      enlargelimits=false, 
      clip=false,
      grid=major
  ]
  \addplot [fill=cyan!20, draw=cyan!80, domain=4:7] {gauss(14,3.41696)} \closedcycle;
  \addplot [very thick,cyan!50!black] {gauss(14,3.416969)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I couldn't get this to work with TeX primitive counters, `\value`, `\def`, `\let`, `\newcommand`, etc.

Comment: `\newcommand\samplesize{100}` works fine ...

Comment: Your code gives an error from the `\section` command, but that is unrelated to the samplesize, and caused by the `standalone` class. Add `varwidth=true` to the class options to fix that.

Comment: Oops. Thanks. It was caused by another macro.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `\newcommand` for this, e.g.

```
\newcommand\samplesize{100}
```

Note also that by default the `standalone` class doesn't seem to handle section headings (among other things), but if you add `varwidth=true` it will work. (Though the `\section` was perhaps just a relic from a complete document.)

Complete code:

```
\documentclass[varwidth=true]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{gauss}{2}{%
  \pgfmathparse{1/(#2*sqrt(2*pi))*exp(-((x-#1)^2)/(2*#2^2))}%
}

\newcommand\samplesize{100}

\begin{document}  
\section{Gaussian distribution}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
      hide y axis,
      axis lines*=center, 
      axis on top,
      no markers, 
      domain=2.5:25.5, 
      samples=\samplesize,
      xlabel=\empty, 
      ylabel=\empty,
      every axis x label/.style={at=(current axis.right of origin),anchor=west},
      every axis y label/.style={at=(current axis.above origin),anchor=south},
      height=5cm, width=12cm,
      xmin = 4, xmax=24,
      xtick={14}, ytick=\empty,
      enlargelimits=false, 
      clip=false,
      grid=major
  ]
  \addplot [fill=cyan!20, draw=cyan!80, domain=4:7] {gauss(14,3.41696)} \closedcycle;
  \addplot [very thick,cyan!50!black] {gauss(14,3.416969)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]